how to build Packages or Artifacts for Node JS from VSCode that cab be deployed in GitLab / Harness pipeline as continuous integration?
how to build Packages or Artifacts for Node JS from VSCode that cab be deployed in GitLab / Harness pipeline as continuous integration?

have created playwright + JS tests that are currently executed using npx command in locally.
Wanted to check in the code and build artifact that can be run in either in Gitlab pipeline or deployed into a Harness pipeline / stage.

Articles suggest to use Actions, but not talking about building a package or artifact that can be deployed
